# Pre defined expressions in LINQ query sytax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression, linq-query-syntax

Is it possible to use a previously defined [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) in LINQ expressions with [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)?  I've created a contrived example to illustrate my question.

```
var tabletTypes = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
//I want to use this expression many times
Expression<Func<Computer, bool>> isTablet = comp => tabletTypes.Contains(comp.Type);

var computers = db.Computers;
var producers = db.Producers;

//I know how to use the expression in fluent syntax
IQueryable<Producer> tabletProducers = computers
                               .Where(isTablet)
                               .Join(producers, 
                                     comp => comp.ProducerId, 
                                     producer => producer.Id, 
                                     (comp, producer) => producer);

//How can I use the expression in query syntax
IQueryable<Producer> tabletProducers2 = from c in computers
                                        join p in producers
                                            on c.ProducerId equals p.Id
                                        where /*How can I use isTablet here?*/
                                        select p;


public class Producer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Computer
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using C# 5 and EF 5.

Comment: You can do that if you work with the expression tree. Have a look at [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), especially the `Expand()` functionality.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I've never used LinqKit.  It looks interesting.

Comment: Yep - that page also explains why my answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `where isTablet.Compile()(c)`. You might want to cache the compiled version.

Comment: Using this produces an Entity Framework error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: To explain my comment a bit further...this answer would work with `IEnumerables`, but not `IQueryables`.